# How to pass additional variable to a listener in .addEventListener

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I'm looking for a away to pass a variable to the function (besides the notification e):

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e));
```

Comment: A little more information would go a long way towards getting the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do add n number of custom arguments using `.bind()`. It'll be available as in order of declaration in `.bind()`

```
function myCallback(customArg, e) {
 ...
}

window.addEventListener("message", myCallback.bind(this, customArg), false);
```

```js
function myCallback(customArg1,customArg2,customArg3,customArg4, e) {
  alert(customArg1 + " " + customArg2 + " " + customArg3 + " " + customArg4)
 }
$('button').click(myCallback.bind(this, 'hello', 'there', 'custom', 'args'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', add.bind(this,10,11));

function add(a,b){
    console.log(a,b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure. It will trap the variable and keep it in scope for the handler function.

```
function handler_factory(myVar) {
    function handler(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(myVar);
    }

    return handler;
}

addEventListener("message", hander_factory("value of myVar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that - call your custom function inside the callback function.

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){ customFunction(e,variable) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like and it's very simple to add extra parameters and even parameter with an object.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('input');
element.addEventListener('click', handle_parameter, false);
element.customParam = 'Custom Param';

var object = {};
object.name = "Chris";
object.surname = "Beckett";

element.customParam2 = object;

function handle_parameter(evt){
  document.getElementById("param1").innerHTML = evt.target.customParam;
  document.getElementById("param2").innerHTML = evt.target.customParam2.name + " " + evt.target.customParam2.surname;  
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="test" />

<p id="param1"></p>
<p id="param2"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Write this below code in your script

```
var proxy = function (method, scope) {
            var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
            return function () {
                return method.apply(scope, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0).concat(aArgs));
            };
    }
```

And Call your event listener. In below code you can use this is nothing but your instance or scope

> window.addEventListener("message",proxy(YOURFUNCTIONNAME,this,arg1,arg2,arg3));